# Django not recognizing the MEDIA_URL path?

Tags: python, django, tinymce

So I'm trying to get TinyMCE up and running on a simple view function, but the path to the tiny_mce.js file gets screwed up. The file is located at /Users/home/Django/tinyMCE/media/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js. I believe that /media/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js is correct, as the development server has no access to files above the root of the Django project folder. In the rendered page, it says in the debugger that the javascript file was not found. This is because it was trying to look through /js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js without addressing the /media/ part of the pathname.

Anyway, here's the script snippet for the javascript in a template named 'simple.html'. `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 tinyMCE.init({
  mode : "textareas",
  theme : "simple"
 });
</script>`

And this is what the vital parts of my settings is like.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(_base, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'tinymce',
)
```

Comment: Have you made sure that you are passing `MEDIA_URL` in the context for that template?

Comment: I didn't before, but now I am. Still getting a "page missing" error though.

Comment: I have a feeling that I might have corrupted the Django module when I installed some extra stuff for Python2.5 via fink. I'm goign to reinstall Django and see if that does anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can either pass it to the template manually as others have suggested or ensure that you are using a [RequestContext](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#id1) instead of plain Context.  RequestContext will automatically populate the context with certain variables including MEDIA_URL and other media-related ones.

Example from docs:

```
def some_view(request):
    # ...
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                              my_data_dictionary,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: This solved the issue with the pathname. However, the javascript isn't loading properly, so I must be doing something else wrong as well.

Answer (score 22):

It looks like your are using the debug server (your url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/...) . Did you install the static serve in your urls.py?

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes':True}),
)
```

The 'show_indexes':True options make possible to browse your media. Go to your medias root http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/ and see it there is something

Comment: Should I use http://localhost:8000/ instead then? Even with the static serve, the debugger still says the javascript file is missing.

Comment: This seems the most logical. @RaDeuX - can you load any static files?

Comment: Great answer! Never know about `'show_indexes':True`. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

It looks like ars has answered your *real* question… But you'll run into another problem: `MEDIA_URL` must be *different* from `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX`. If they aren't, the `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` will take precedence. I usually fix this by changing `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` to `/admin-media/`.

Comment: Hm, didn't know that. It's not part of my issue, but I'll keep that in mind if I ever hit a huge wall like this again.

Comment: It turns out that you were right. Even though my MEDIA_URL was http://localhost:8000/media/, it was essentially still the same folder. So not only does the pathname must be different but the folder that it's referring to must be different as well. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Do you have the media context processor in your settings?

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
)
```

You might also try putting the following in your settings to see if the debug messages reveal anything:

```
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
```

Comment: I do have the debug mode on, but there are no errors. All it is is that the javascript file doesn't load.

Comment: Now that I look closely, even with the pathname being corrected, it still doesn't load.

<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript">
   1Page not found: /media/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js

Comment: Try view source on the page after setting TEMPLATE_DEBUG=True .. the debug message might be within the html head/script section where your media_url is referenced.

Comment: Do you have a URL for /media?  This page might help: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: Do I need a URL for media? Can't I access the javascript from a view function that accesses the javascript file?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "accesses".  Your view function is simply rendering the template -- so it returns the HTML to the browser.  The browser parses the HTML and makes another call to find related files like the script URL.  Do you have a separate view to render that URL (js file)?  If not, then use the link I provided to django docs, which explains how to statically serve that file in your local/dev environment.  Presumably your production server handles this by having an entry to resolve /media files statically.

Comment: (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes':True}), is what I put for media files. I also can't access anything in the media folder index, including the folder itself, as it gives me a permission denied page.

Comment: Can you confirm that your settings.MEDIA_ROOT is correct?  Try printing it and check the path.  Also, permission denied is security related, so make sure you have read permissions on the filesystem for that directory.

Comment: Now that I look at it more carefully, the /media folder is readable to everyone.

Comment: I found the issue. The ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX was set as /media/, so I changed it to /media/admin/. David Wolever was right. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Please read the official Django DOC carefully and you will find the most fit answer.

The best and easist way to solve this is like below.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The related url is: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot for your help everyone. I was able to solve it as

**settings.py -->**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/patrick/Documents/code/projects/test/media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/media/'
```

**urls.py -->**

```
(r'^media/(?P<path>,*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

**index.html -->**

```
img src="/media/images/logo.jpg"
```

Again, thanks a lot, I was going crazy trying to find out how to do all of this. This solution worked for me on a Django version 1.2.5 Development server running Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem,
I have a one-page-app and Apparently I had a newbie mistake that made django miss my media path i had this:

```
url(r'^', home, name="home"),
```

instead of this:

```
url(r'^$', home, name="home"),
```

the missing `$` made my url pattern miss my media url

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem, this is how I got it done.

If you are using a FileField in your model class instead of MEDIA_URL use .url member to access the url of your file. 
For eg: something like this

```
href = "{{ some_object.file_name.url }}"
```

here file_name is the FileField in model class.